# How to do the following trigonometric simplification: $ \frac{1- \cos (3\alpha) }{1- \cos (\alpha)} = (1 + 2\cos (\alpha)^2) $

Tags: trigonometry

This is probably a trivial question but I don't understand it. Somehow I can't seem to understand how to simplify this expression:

$$ \frac{1- \cos (3\alpha) }{1- \cos (\alpha)} = (1 + 2\cos (\alpha))^2 $$

Comment: Clearly there is no generalization of the formula as you stated. Just pick $n=2$ and $\alpha=\pi$

Comment: Using $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$ you have just the polynomial quotient $$\frac{4X^3-3X-1}{X-1}$$ which is equal to $(1+2X)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using capital $A$, so bare with me.

We will prove that $$1-\cos3A=(1-\cos A)(1+2\cos A)^2$$

First we will show that $$\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A$$

Indeed, we know that $$\cos(x+y)=\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y$$

Thus, for $x=2A, y=A$ we obtain: $$(*):\cos 3A=\cos 2A\cos A-\sin 2A\sin A$$

but from $(*)$ we see that: $\cos 2A=\cos^2A-\sin^2A$

and we know that $\sin 2A=2\sin A\cos A$

So,$$\cos 3A=(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)\cos A-2\sin^2A\cos A\\=(2\cos^2A-1)\cos A-2(1-\cos^2)\cos A\\= 4\cos^3A-3\cos A$$

Now we have $$1-\cos3A=1-4\cos^3A+3\cos A$$

But $$(1-\cos A)(1+2\cos A)^2=\\(1-\cos A)(\cos^2A+2\cos A+1)=\\1-4\cos^3A+3\cos A$$

and we are done.